70's ? Sci fi film about 2 sets of Aliens living on Earth fighting for supremacy
I remember seeing this film as a kid which would make it mid 70's but the film may be older.
The main hero of the film is one of three Aliens (good guys) sent to earth to track down and eliminate three bad guy aliens. Both sets of Aliens look human until seen through special glasses, a bit like in "they live" but its not the same film. He is befriended by a girl and confides in her and together they track down the three bad Aliens only to be killed by a fourth bad alien. The final scene shows the last remaining bad alien walking away with the camera view through the dead good alien's glasses.

Possibly related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/5810/seeking-a-1960s-sci-fi-movie-about-a-female-humanoid-robot/5816#5816 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32153/two-warring-planets-settling-their-differences-on-earth-secretly.

Sounds like The Love War from 1970 with Lloyd Bridges and Angie Dickinson. From Wiki:

Two warring planets choose to settle their conflict over which of them will take over the planet Earth, each sending a trio of soldiers to the Earth to do personal combat to the death. The loser's planet cedes the conquest of the earth to the winner of the combat. The combatants, disguised as human beings, can only identify each other by using special visors.

It ends in the manner you've described; the good alien is killed by a bad alien and we then see through his visors on the ground that

the 4th alien who killed him was the woman he befriended all along.

The film is currently available on Youtube in 5 parts; here's part 1.
